# ¿Como concatenar valores dentro de un for en una variable?

Tags: php

Es decir lo que quiero realizar es lo siguiente

```
 //tengo esta variable 
 $mivariable = '';
 $new_data = array(1,3);
 //y tengo este for
 foreach($new_data as $id){
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM  carrito WHERE id_carrito = :id');
    $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $response = $stmt->fetch();
    $mivariable .= $response['link'];

}

return $mivariable;
```

Lo que intento es hacer que cada valor que consulta mediante el ciclo for lo concatene a la variable mivariable, y lo que hace hasta el momento es solo tomarme el ultimo valor , es decir el valor de la consulta del ultimo recorrido.

¿Como hago para que cada ves que recorra el arreglo y valla y consulte el valor, eso lo concatene a la variable $mivariable?

Comment: Cuantos registros te retorna el select? solo 1 para cada caso?

Comment: La estructura del foreach es correcta y si haces un echo de la variable después del bucle sale bien, de modo que el problema son los datos que vienen de la consulta. Si puedes haz un var_dump($response) antes de asignar a $mivariable para ver lo que trae, es posible que la primera id=1 no se encuentre o el valor del link esté vacío y por eso sólo ves el segundo valor.